# Is the correct form "No Seconds without it"?

Tags: grammar

I couldnt find out if it is the only correct form to express, that someone should not spend even 1 second without *something*.

In my language, it can be directly expressed (verbal alternative for: `not-1 second without it`).

In English, what is the most appropriate equivalent? As I think, it's:

`No Seconds Without it`

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most natural way to express this would be "not one second", "not (even) a second".

Examples:

- Q: "How long can you go without your phone?" / A: "Not one second."
- "He doesn't want to spend even a second without that phone of his."

"No seconds" sounds awkward, though I suppose you could say "He won't go seconds without it, let alone minutes".

When I read your title "no seconds" I thought instead of the colloquial meaning of "seconds" (which can mean either "second helping/serving" or "dessert").  "No seconds without finishing your vegetables first!"

Answer (score 1):

> No seconds without it

doesn't violate any grammatical rules that I know of, but it's not very clear and it's not natural sounding.  I would say:

> Don't spend a second without it
>   or
>   You shouldn't spend a second without it

or something similar.

Comment: thanks, but i have to use the separate phrase/slogan, not inside the full sentence, like that you said. however, thanks

Comment: I don't think there is such a phrase in English.